# How to dynamically set a gitlab executor via tags on the job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Context**

I am currently trying to implement a homolog/production environment with Gitlab, and have installations of Gitlab Runners on two different servers, both with the same configurations and dependencies, in order to run the build project.

I've written the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and tried on both runners, using the `tag: runner_name` and it worked just fine. The problem is that I `cannot assign the executor` when the pipeline runs.

A example of what I wrote:

```
job1:
 stage: setup
 variables:
    RUNNER_TAG: "executor-default"
 rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /development/
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "executor-default"
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /production/
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "executor-production"
      when: always
      allow_failure: false

 tags:
   - $RUNNER_TAG
 script: 
   - npm install
```

This job should run on the `executor-default` if the target is the development branch and on the `executor-production` if the target branch is the production. On every execution I've tried it ran on the `executor-default`. I have checked the documentation and forum, but no clue on how to implement or fix this behavior. How to dynamically set a gitlab executor via tags on the job?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "tags" keyword with 2 values (executor-default & executor-production) and used "CI_RUNNER_TAGS" predefined variable. Try below code.

```
job1:
 stage: setup
 tags:
    - "executor-default"
    - "exector-production"
 rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /development/
    - CI_RUNNER_TAGS == "executor-default"
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /production/
    - CI_RUNNER_TAGS == "executor-production"
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
```